# One of the PHP posted values is not right

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I have a registration form for companies, with multiple fields. All but one are working fine... The one that isn't working was added later, and it always stores the same number, but I can't figure out why.

I've checked:

- Default values in the MySQL database: nothing there.
- Pulled the value of the input with JS from the console: it's the right field name and pulls the right value
- Verified that there is only one field with that name: fine.
- Looked for the number that gets stored in many included files: I can't find it.

The minute I submit the form, `$_POST["empresa_cuit "]` always carries the same number, which is unrelated to what I put in the input field.

Here's some of my code:

The 2 functions are:

```
function defaultForm() {
        global $url, $url_prefix, $user_prefix;
        global $root;
        global $selected;
        global $id;
        $empresa = get_empresa($id);
        $empresa_txt = mysql_fetch_array($empresa);
    ?>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='update_datos'>
            <h2>Empresa <?php echo $empresa_txt['empresa']; ?></h2>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <label for="empresa">Nombre de la empresa</label>
                <div class="input">
                     <input type="text" name="empresa" value="<?php echo $empresa_txt['empresa']; ?>" class="required" title="Este campo es obligatorio."/>      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <label for="empresa_cuit">CUIT</label>
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="empresa_cuit" id="empresa_cuit" class="required digits"  minlength="11" maxlength="11" title="Ingrese los 11 dígitos del CUIT, sin guiones." value="<?php //echo $empresa_txt['empresa_cuit'];?>"/>
                    <br  /><span class="aclaracion">Ingrese sólo números.</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
                <label for="empresa_tel">Tel&eacute;fono</label>
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="empresa_cod_tel" id="empresa_cod_tel" maxlength="6" size="6" class="required digits areacode" value="<?php echo $empresa_txt['empresa_cod_tel']; ?>"  title="Debe ingresar un c&oacute;digo de &aacute;rea v&aacute;lido (s&oacute;lo n&uacute;meros)."/>
                    <input type="text" name="empresa_tel" class="required digits"  value="<?php echo $empresa_txt['empresa_tel']; ?>" title="Debe ingresar un tel&eacute;fono v&aacute;lido (s&oacute;lo n&uacute;meros)."/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Actualizar" class='white button'/>
            <input name="filter" type="hidden" value="processForm">
            <!-- hidden value points the switch to processing -->
        </form>

    <?php return; } #/ End of defaultForm ?>
```

-

```
function processForm()  {
    echo $empresa_cuit = intval($_POST['empresa_cuit']);
```

...

I've moved this line to the very top, so that I can monitor the value right away. The rest of the function is irrelevant after that, it ALWAYS shows the same number! The number has a phone number format, so I thought it might have been related to the phone fields (empresa_cod_tel and empresa_tel), but it doesn't matter what I put in there, the number in the CUIT field remains the same.

Could you help me troubleshoot this some more? I can't paste every related piece of code in here now, but let me know if you'd like to see anything else...

Comment: What datatype is the field in your mysql table and what number is stored inside the table?

Comment: Agree with the above. You must be exceeding the max limit of the datatype. Try changing it to a datatype that accepts a higher value.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What do you see if you write a print_r($_POST) when the form is posted? Can you see correct value there?

Comment: It's an int with a length of 20, intended to store a 11 digit number. I don't think this is it...

Comment: Becquerel, you're right... print_r will show the right number. But how does it change if I put these 2 lines in a row?? print_r($_POST);  echo $empresa_cuit = intval($_POST['empresa_cuit']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only thought is this:  if you are using a 32 bit integer and the phone number you are entering evaluates to greater than 2147483647, intval will always return 2147483647.

I'd change it to store the phone number as a string.

Comment: That was it! I never thought mentioning the number would help, but it's exactly that one, and now that I've changed the type to string, it works fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have at DB int column, change it to varchar, problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I continue the thread here instead of in the comments since we may be on to something.

So if you write $_POST['empresa_cuit'] you should see the correct value?

What is the value? Can there be any character in there that makes intval unable to parse it - in that case intval returns 0.